# Adding leading zeros in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, leading-zero

I have a Spark `DataFrame` called `nfe`, which contains a column called `NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE` that is currently formatted as a string (although it is completely numeric). This column should have entries that are either 11 or 14 characters in length, but there are entries of 9, 10, 12, and 13 character length for which I need to add leading zeros.

However, I cannot use the `sprintf` function as I do in R:

```
nfe$CNPJ_EMITENTE <- ifelse(nfe$length_emit == 9, sprintf("%00s", nfe$NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE), nfe$NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE)

# Error in sprintf("%00s", nfe$NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE) : unsupported type
```

Is there a simple way to add 2 leading zeros for 9 and 12 length entries and 1 leading zero for 11 and 13 length entries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R's `ifelse` has trouble with sparkR s4 objects. An easy solution (for this and a lot of other troublesome data manipulations) is to make it into a SQL query:

```
#Setup SQL context
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
sqlContext <- SQLContext(sc)

# Register your dataframe as a table
registerTempTable(df, 'df')

#Query your dataframe
sql(sqlContext, "SELECT [other variables], 
                        case when LENGTH(NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE) in (9,12) then concat('00',NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE)
                        when LENGTH(NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE) in (10,13) then concat('0',NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE)
                        else NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE end as NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE
                  FROM df")
```

To select all the variablles in the dataframe, the query would look like this:

```
sql(sqlContext, "SELECT df.*, 
                        case when LENGTH(NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE) in (9,12) then concat('00',NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE)
                        when LENGTH(NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE) in (10,13) then concat('0',NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE)
                        else NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE end as NFE_CNPJ_EMITENTE_RECODED
                  FROM df")
```

Comment: I still seem to be having trouble.

First, `registerTempTable(df, 'df')` is deprecated, and I used `createOrReplaceTempView(nfe, 'nfe')` instead. Is this correct?

Comment: Second, I'm not terribly comfortable with SQL queries - in the above `sql` command, does the `[other variables]` refer to every other column in the dataframe?

Comment: Moreover, when I run the above code, I receive an error message in each line of the sql command: `Error: unexpected numeric constant in "sql(sqlContext,  "SELECT` and `unexpected symbol in "    FROM nfe"`

Comment: Apologies for all of the comments, but am I doing a simple thing wrong?

Comment: In order for your questions
1) That should work
2) Yes, it refers to having them all in a comma-delimited list, e.g. `var1, var2, var3 ...`. If you have many variables you can select all of them with `select *`, but you'll want to change the name of your recoded variable to avoid having two columns of the same name
3) The error is likely a SQL syntax issue. If you comment your full query here I can take a look

Comment: Also, there's definitely a syntax error that I put in there (sorry). Since the `SELECT` statement is wrapped in " quotes, I obviously should not have used " to define my string constant 0s. Answer edited to fix that, 0s now wrapped in ' quotes. You were getting  `unexpected numeric constant` because I ended the quoted select statement and then there was a numeric 0, which the `sql` function had no clue what to do with.